# QtDesigner code doesn't work in Pycharm

Tags: python, pyqt, designer

So I was fooling around with QtDesigner today, and I got the design I wanted for my program, however, when converting the .ui file to a .py file, the file just seems to close. I can see that I'm missing something here, but I simply have no clue what it is.

```
/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8

    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(845, 620)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Times New Roman"))
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Times New Roman"))
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Times New Roman"))
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(48)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(36)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 845, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ordrebekræftelse", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tilbud", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Faktura", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Aaskov Gardiner", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "  v/ Bent H. Troelsen", None))
```

I'd really appreciate any help given.

Comment: Read the documentation: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html
(hint: The generated .py files are not supposed to be immediately runnable)

Comment: I've looked through the documentation, but I still can't see exactly what to do. I've noticed that maybe I need an __init__ definition, but I'm completely lost on what to do next.

Comment: You have generated a python file with a class in it from the .ui file. Now you must write another python file which uses this class. See the above linked answer (the possible duplicate), or the first example in the tutorial I linked to in my first comment, for how to do this.